# How do I implement an operator for a class nested in a generic struct?

Tags: generics, nested, operators, swift, equality

When I nest a class inside a generic struct and try to implement the equality operator, like this:

```
struct Outer<T> {
    class Inner : Equatable {}
}

@infix func == <T>(lhs: Outer<T>.Inner, rhs: Outer<T>.Inner) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run the project:

```
While emitting IR SIL function @_TFCC4Test5Outer5InnerCU__fMS1_FT_S1_ for 'init' at .../Testing.swift:20:11
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

However, it works fine when I do the same thing without nesting the class:

```
class MyClass : Equatable {}

@infix func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

Is this a bug with the compiler, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is a bug in the compiler, you should report it.

Comment: Yes currently Class variables are unsupported...which could be the cause here

Comment: There are no class variables used here, and the same thing happens if they're both structs.

Comment: Yep, compiler bug when translating SIL into LLVM IR. You can pinpoint it by doing swift -emit-sil and seeing that it works. If you use swift -emit-ir (or just swift), it ends up in an infinite loop, for me.

Comment: Under beta 5 I get a segfault with something as simple as `struct Outer<T> { class Inner {} }` (removing the generic makes it work, doesn't seem to matter if either is struct or class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting a `class` or `struct` in a generic type struct is now flagged as invalid by XCode6 Beta6

[image]

Comment: Any idea what the logic is here or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: As of Xcode 6.1.1 it is still flagged as invalid. I would say it is a swift language feature. You probably have to ask in the Apple Swift forum for the rationale behind it. It is not considered a compiler bug ( a compiler bug is, from swift team POV, what causes XCode to crash)

Answer (score 1):

You could define the Inner class in a separate file or space, defining its operator then make a var of that type in your inner class:

```
class Inner: Equatable {}
func == (left: Inner, right: Inner) -> Bool {
    return true
}
struct Outer {
    var myVar: Inner
}
```

As of beta 6