# Xcode build error when I add enum to generic class?

Tags: generics, enums, swift

Why do I get an error when I add enum to generic class:

```
class TestClass<T>{ 
    enum TestEnum {
        case test
    }  
}
```

Error:

```
1.  While type-checking 'ExampleTest' at /Users/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/ExampleTest.swift:11:1
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

But I don't get an error when I do this :

```
class TestClass{ 
    enum TestEnum {
        case test
    }  
}
```

or this:

```
class TestClass<T>{ 
}
```

Comment: Your first two examples are exactly identical - is it possible you may have posted the same snippet twice?

Comment: Compiler bug with the combination of generic class and nested enum. [File a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and de-nest the enumeration for now as a workaround.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Thanks, corrected the example.

Comment: @NateCook Yeah it looks like it, do you see the same behavior when compiling the code? If so, you could add your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't nest any type inside a generic one and vice versa.
In other words, you can't do things like these for classes, structs, and enums:

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner { }
}
```

and

```
class Outer {
    class Inner<T> { }
}
```

and even

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner<T> { }
}
```

Apple folks [explained](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1046539#1046539) the reason for the restriction:

> It's an implementation limitation. We'll remove the restriction once
>   our compiler and runtime are able to correctly handle types nested in
>   generic contexts.

P.S. Sorry that I post the answer so late but the issue is still there (XCode 6.2).

There was a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127250/how-do-i-implement-an-operator-for-a-class-nested-in-a-generic-struct), by the way.

Comment: Swift 3.1 and XCode 8.3.2 support this now